# Command to download video files with firefox

Tags: firefox

```
<a href="http://example.com/example.mp4" download>download me</a>
```

If you click on the link it triggers a download because of the download attribute, but i need it as an command, some thing like

```
view-source:http://example.com
```

so in this case i would need

```
download:http://example.com/example.mp4
```

(it does not work of course)

I hope you get my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such command you can enter in the browser to accomplish what you're trying to do. If what you're looking for is a way to download files for which you have the URL but without having to create a hyperlink, then [SaveTarget.As](http://savetarget.as) might suit your needs. You just have to paste the URL, and it will create a hyperlink for you.

**Note**: I am the owner of SaveTarget.As.

If instead you have a website where you want to invoke a download without the user having to click on the button, you can use the jQuery or JavaScript `.click()` method to accomplish this. Here's some more info on that: [HTML DOM click() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

Comment: Already solved, but thanks anyway. I wish i knew your site :)

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you solved your problem. If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as your accepted answer, as this helps me build my reputation on the site :)